# Анимация при загрузки сайта HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, loading

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать такую же анимацию при загрузки сайта как здесь [Hyam](https://www.hyam.de/en). Без надписи, чтобы при открытие сайта анимировнно верхняя часть чёрной полосы уезжала вверх, а нижняя вниз. Желательно только на HTML и CSS. Зарание спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#loading-screen::before, #loading-screen::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

#loading-screen::before {
  animation-name: loadingScreen1;
}

#loading-screen::after {
  animation-name: loadingScreen2;
}

@keyframes loadingScreen1 {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes loadingScreen2 {
  to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading-screen"></div>

<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! :)

Comment: @Майя не за что! :)